# numbers in cosine similarity space

Tags: math

I want to represent real numbers in some range to a vector space such that numbers which are closer are also closer in the vector space, closeness can be measured using cosine distance.

For example, between 0-100, 9 and 10 should have cosine similarity close to 1 and 9 and 100 should have cosine similarity close to -1.

How can achieve such a mapping ? I am thinking of trying a neural net encoder but is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: This is a strange thing to do. The purpose of cosine similarity is to compare vectors like we compare real numbers--you want to go the other way. Comparing real numbers is easy--why do you want to make it more complicated? What is the context here? Besides that, a vector space (usually) has more members than other sets, do to the multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do in the special case of a 2-dimensional vector space. I will illustrate for the range `[0,100]`, though it would be easy enough to generalize to other intervals.

Think of the unit circle as being an analog clock centered at the origin. Map a point `x` in `[0,100]` to the position of the second hand `0.3x` seconds into a minute. For `x = 0`, the second hand points to 12 and the corresponding vector would be `<0,1>`. For `x = 50`, the second hand would point to 3 and `x` would map to `<1,0>`. For `x = 100`, the second hand would point down to 6 and `x` would map to `<0,-1>`.

The formula for the mapping is:

```
f(x) = <sin(1.8*x),cos(1.8*x)>  #measured in degrees
```

Here is a Python implementation, generalized to handle arbitrary intervals:

```
from math import sin, cos, radians, sqrt

def to_vector(x,a,b):
    m = 180/(b-a)
    theta = radians(m*(x-a))
    return (sin(theta),cos(theta))

def similarity(v1,v2):
    dot = sum(x*y for x,y in zip(v1,v2))
    norm1 = sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in v1))
    norm2 = sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in v2))
    return dot/(norm1*norm2)
```

For example,

```
>>> u = to_vector(9,0,100)
>>> u
(0.2789911060392293, 0.9602936856769431)
>>> v = to_vector(10,0,100)
>>> v
(0.3090169943749474, 0.9510565162951535)
>>> w = to_vector(100,0,100)
>>> w
(1.2246467991473532e-16, -1.0)
>>> similarity(v,u)
0.9995065603657316
>>> similarity(v,w)
-0.9510565162951536
```

**On Edit:** Here is a more abstract approach which can be used to construct examples in any dimension.

Start with any continuous one-to-one mapping `g: [a,b] \rightarrow R^n` (where `R^n` is n-dimensional Euclidean space). Since it is one-to-one, `g(a) != g(b)`. Let `m` be the midpoint of the line segment connecting `g(a)` and `g(b)`. Thus `m = (g(a) + g(b))/2`. Define another function as follows:

```
f(x) = g(x) - m
```

It is easy to see that:

1. If `x` and `y` are close together then the cosine similarity between `f(x)` and `f(y)` is close to `1`
2. If `x` is close to `a` and `y` is close to `b` then the cosine similarity between `f(x)` and `f(y)` is close to `-1`.

By appropriate choice of `g` you can construct some interesting examples, e.g. `g` could be a parameterization of a complete twist of a helix in `R^3`.